# api in c# .net examples

Tags: .net, interface

1. What is an API in C# .Net?
2. How can I create it?
3. Could you please suggest me some useful links regarding the same. 
   I searched Google.com to get examples, but :(

Thanks.

Comment: For what do you want to have API on C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) stands for Application Programming Interface.

You do no create an API by itself. An API is a way to give programmatic access something (like a library), so you first need to have something that you want to give access to.

Comment: Could you please provide link to examples ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. It is a very abstract concept, you need to be more specific as to what you want to do.